# Android missing click after backspace/delete of character

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I'm new to Android, probably missing something simple here...

I have a `TextWatcher`, watching an EditText box. For test purposes, I have the following code, which does nothing but clear the EditText box, then rewrite the original EditText contents.

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

    mCheckAmount.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    mCheckAmount.setText("");           //Clear EditText box
    mCheckAmount.setText(s.toString()); //Write the string back
    mCheckAmount.addTextChangedListener(this);
  }
```

This works fine in the emulator.

When I send it to the phone (Original Droid with 2.2.2 on it) I can enter numbers into the EditText (I have it set to only accept numbers). If I delete a single digit from the EditText box, I have to enter a new digit TWO times before it appears. In other words, after deleting a character from the EditText, the next click is ignored.

I have no idea where I am going wrong with this.

Thanks in advance for any help.